# Which is more expensive: using variables or using for loop instead of declaring variables to hold temp results?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

I'm dealing with this problem:check if an array is Bean array or not. An array is defined to be a Bean array if it meets the following conditions: If it contains a 9 then it also contains a 13. If it contains a 7 then it does not contain a 16.

I have tried two ways to solving it. but i'm not sure which code is considered to be more efficient in terms of "space time complexity" or relating to Big O.

Here are two ways i wrote:

## 1

```java
static int isBean2(int[] a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i]==9){
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
                if(a[j]==13)
                    break;
                if(j==a.length-1 && a[j]!=13)
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        if(a[i]==7) {
            for(int k=0;k<a.length;k++)
                if(a[k]==16)
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

## 2

```java
static int isBean(int[] a)
{
    int n=0;
    int t=0;
    int seven=0;
    int sixteen=0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i]==9)
            n=1;
        if(a[i]==13)
            t=1;
        if(a[i]==7)
            seven=1;
        if(a[i]==16)
            sixteen=1;        
    }
    if(n==1 && t==0)
        return 0;
    if(seven==1 && sixteen==1)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

The second code seems silly but, Any one with better answer, please?

Comment: Try to go through both methods, assuming you get handed a list that contains one million 7s and nothing else. How many times would you read the whole list in both cases?

Comment: Strangely enough i like the second method, however I would add a small check in the second method to see if the criteria is met so that i dont have to go through the entire array and i can break when the conditions are met.

Comment: Arpan Kanthal, in the second method let us say we found 9 at the very beginning what can we do if we find 13  at the end index? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution has worst case complexity O(n^2) while the second has O(n) but is wrong according to the requirement mentioned above.

For the 2nd solution, you can make following corrections, after the loop ends:

```java
if ((n == 1 && t == 1) || (seven == 1 && sixteen == 0))
  return 1;
return 0;
```

Comment: I accept corrections on the second code. but the solution is not wrong. for example, It's ok  not to have both 9 and 13 at all. But if 9 appear 13 should also be there.

Comment: Without the correction, the function `isBean` will return 1 with array `[1]`

Comment: If that is fine then I guess I misunderstood the statement

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 has only 1 for loop meaning it has an O(n) efficiency while Solution 1 is O(n^2) since it has a nested for loop. This is because the inside for loop runs the code a.length (n) times and the outer for loop runs the inner loop a.length (n) times, making a nested for loop's efficiency O(n^2).

The correction to your 2nd piece of code is as Vatsal Jain stated above

```
if ((n == 1 && t == 1) || (seven == 1 && sixteen == 0))
  return 1;
return 0;
```

assuming a return value of 1 is a bean array.

Comment: as I wrote on Vatsal Jain's answer there are only two conditions that should return 0. Otherwise it should return 1.